# Flutter TextEditingController value resets on widget build

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to set the value of a `TextEditingController` during the widget build method.

The problem is that every time the widget rebuilds, the _controller value resets to to it's original state and the new value disappears:

`final TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();`

```
Widget _build(BuildContext context) {
   
   myString = "Value only available in widget build";

   new TextField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
      controller: _controller..text = myString,
   ),
```

}

In the above example `myString` is declared during widget build. Unfortunately, it cannot be declared duing `initState`, hence my problem.

How can I set the _controller value only during the first build and prevent it from resetting to it's original value after the widget rebuilds itself?

Any suggestions?

Comment: why does the variable need to be declared in the widget build? The widget build gets ran each time setState is called. so you should not declare variables in the widget build.

Comment: Because the variable get's it's value within a `StoreConnector` and it's refreshed every few seconds.

Comment: Actually, for this particular variable. I don't care if it's refreshed or not after the initial declaration, however there is not way to easily set it's value in the `initState`.

Answer (score 0):

From what you are saying, you don't need to use StoreConnector for widget you don't want to update when updating your store. You could definitely do something like this:

```
String? myString;

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   if (myString == null) {
     //Once myString is assigned it will not update.
     myString = StoreProvider.of<YourClass>(context).state.myString;
     _controller.text = myString;
   }
   return TextField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
      controller: _controller,
   );
}
```

Also, if you want to do it with `StoreConnector<>` you can do:

```
 return StoreConnector(
   builder: (context, value) {
     return TextField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
      controller: _controller,
     );
   }, 
   rebuildOnChange: false, //Add this line to stop rebuilding when store changes.
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set text controller value into initState() of your page so it will be prevent it to reset after rebuild

Comment: But the user specifically mentions that he cannot set the value because value is only available in the build method of the widget. So, he cannot use initState in this case.